# Class Model not found in Doctrine 2.2 + CodeIgniter 2.1

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

I have set up a project with CodeIgniter 2.1 and Doctrine 2.2, following the instruction on 
Doctrine [cookbook](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html). The EntityManager works, but when I try to load entity models, it 
gives me error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Users' not found in /Volumes/Data/Projects/myproject/application/controllers/home.php on line 10
```

This is my home.php file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

//require_once(APPPATH.'models/Users.php');

class Home extends CI_Controller {
  public function index()
  {
    $em = $this->doctrine->em;
    $users = new Users;     
    //$user = $em->find("Users", 1);
    $em->flush(); // dummy
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
  }
}
```

If I uncomment line 3: `require_once(APPPATH.'models/Users.php');`, then 
it works perfectly.

How can I make the models auto-loaded?

Is the autoload mechanism handled by the bootstrap in libraries/ Doctrine.php, isn't it?

```
    $entitiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('models', rtrim(APPPATH, "/" )); 
    $entitiesClassLoader->register();
```

Please anyone give me insight about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have a namespace line inside of your Users.php file?

If so then you will need to add a "use" statement to your controller code so the php namespace system knows where to look for your entities.

If not then verify that your entitiesClassLoader is actually being called and that APPPATH has the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with CI and Doctrine so don't know if Doctrine should load the models or where it loads them, but you should try to do it yourselft, not with an include but this way :

In the Controller :
$this->load->model('Users');

Or as Autoload in application/config/autoload.php and load the model in the Array.