# Codeigniter, Doctrine, class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I followed the instructions in http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup but in the test controller when I write

```
$u = new User;
```

It gives

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'User' not found
```

error. I implemented exactly what the tutorial asks for.

There is a similar question([Class Model not found in Doctrine 2.2 + CodeIgniter 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396796/class-model-not-found-in-doctrine-2-2-codeigniter-2-1)) I've also checked the proposed solution but my model does not have a namespace and my APPPATH is defined properly.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I followed another one(http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2) this one worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$u = new User();
```

instead of

```
$u = new User;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be :
$u = new User(); and also you need to include your user class in project. You need to autoload all generated classes.